# Does EF upsert have to be done manually?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I want to upsert reference members of an existing entity.

Do I have to write specific code for the upsert?

meaning: I have to check if I'm handling an existing reference member or a new one.

Is there any other simple way to do so?

What happens when you do only `Save` ?

```
  public void SaveCofiguration(MamConfiguration_V1Ui itemUi)
        {
            var itemEf = mMamConfiguration_V1UiToEfConvertor.ConvertToNewEf(itemUi);

            using (var maMDBEntities = new MaMDBEntities())
            {
                IDal<MamConfiguration_V1> mamConfigurationDal = mDalFactory.GetDal<MamConfiguration_V1>(maMDBEntities);

                mamConfigurationDal.Save(itemEf);
            }
        }

         public MamConfiguration_V1 GetById(object id)
        {           
                id.ThrowIfNull("id");

                int configurationId = Convert.ToInt32(id);

                var result =
                    mMaMDBEntities.MamConfiguration_V1.SingleOrDefault(item => item.ConfigurationId == configurationId);

                return result;

        }

       public MamConfiguration_V1 Save(MamConfiguration_V1 item)
        {

                item.ThrowIfNull("item");

                var itemFromDB = GetById(item.ConfigurationId);

                if (itemFromDB != null)
                {
                    UpdateEfItem(itemFromDB, item);

                   // if (mMaMDBEntities.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(itemFromDB).State == EntityState.Detached)
//                    {
  //                      mMaMDBEntities.MamConfiguration_V1.AddObject(itemFromDB);
    //                }

                    // Attached object tracks modifications automatically
                    mMaMDBEntities.SaveChanges();

                    return item;
                }





       private void UpdateEfItem(MamConfiguration_V1 itemFromDb, MamConfiguration_V1 itemFromUi)
            {
                itemFromDb.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;

                itemFromDb.Description = itemFromUi.Description;

                itemFromDb.StatusId = itemFromUi.StatusId;

                itemFromDb.Name = itemFromUi.Name;

                itemFromDb.NumericTraffic = itemFromUi.NumericTraffic;

                itemFromDb.PercentageTraffic = itemFromUi.PercentageTraffic;

                itemFromDb.Type = itemFromUi.NumericTraffic;

                foreach (var item in itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.ToList())
                {
                    if (itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.All(b => b.BrowserVersionId != item.BrowserVersionId))
                    {
                        mMaMDBEntities.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.DeleteObject(item);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Count; i++)
                {
                    var element = itemFromUi.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.ElementAt(i);
                    var item = itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.SingleOrDefault(b => b.BrowserVersionId == element.BrowserVersionId);
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        // copy properties from element to item
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        element.Browser = mMaMDBEntities.Browsers.Single(browserItem =>
                            browserItem.BrowserID == element.BrowserID);

                        //element.MamConfiguration_V1 = itemFromDb;

                        //have also tried: element.MamConfiguration_V1 = null;

                        //element.MamConfiguration_V1Reference = null;

                        itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Add(element);
                    }
                }
            }
```

But I would have expecte `Save(itemUi)` and `SaveChanges()` to work fine. No?

Comment: One option is to use a unique index and do an insert: `DbUtils.IgnoreErrors(_db, () => DbUtils.InsertEntity(_db, someEntity),
  DbUtils.IsDuplicateInsertError);` from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042107/handle-exceptions-in-entity-framework-4/34670770#34670770

Comment: Can the code be reduced to the minimum required for the question? Also, commented code makes the question very unclear and the bad indentation doesn't help either.

Comment: OP asks for UPSERT, and for "check if I have existing reference or a new one". These are essentially two different things, hence answers are split. Most of them tackle the latter issue and do some thing like AddOrUpdate on the app side. At this moment, only jjxtra's answer about FlexLabs.Upsert provides a true upsert executed on the database.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(DbContext context, UEntity entity)
{
    context.Entry(entity).State = entity.Id == 0 ?
                                   EntityState.Added :
                                   EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1889944.aspx/1

Comment: What happens when you do only `Save` ?

Comment: I'm dealing with upsert to navigation members. How can it be done there?

Comment: This isn't right for the common case when you construct your entire entity - with its primary key (could be composite) - and then you want to either update that row (if it already exists in the DB) or you want to add it if it doesn't. The AddOrUpdate method is better.

Comment: Threading issue: If two threads meet at context.SaveChanges and both are in .Added state.

Comment: @jjxtra Doesn't that mean both entities are separate ? Two threads coming from same added then those are two different entities

Comment: What if I do not have Id generated automatically ?

Comment: Just a warning for all less-experienced readers: this is NOT a true 'upsert'. This is NOT executed 100% at the database and is NOT atomic, which MAY lead to duplicated rows under high load. See answer from jjxtra about `FlexLabs.Upsert` library  for a solution that provides a real upsert (though ONLY for SOME databases that are supported by the nuget)

Answer (score 20):

To avoid the overhead of a query and then insert, or throwing exceptions, you can take advantage of the underlying database support for merges or upserts.

This nuget package does the job pretty well: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FlexLabs.EntityFrameworkCore.Upsert/

Github: https://github.com/artiomchi/FlexLabs.Upsert

Example:

```
DataContext.DailyVisits
    .Upsert(new DailyVisit
    {
        // new entity path
        UserID = userID,
        Date = DateTime.UtcNow.Date,
        Visits = 1,
    })
    // duplicate checking fields
    .On(v => new { v.UserID, v.Date })
    .WhenMatched((old, @new) => new DailyVisit
    {
        // merge / upsert path
        Visits = old.Visits + 1,
    })
    .RunAsync();
```

The underlying generated sql does a proper upsert. This command runs right away and does not use change tracking, so that is one limitation.

Answer (score 1):

See 'AddOrUpdate' method of System.Data.Entity.Migrations.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.idbsetextensions.addorupdate%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

public void Save(Person person) {
    var db = new MyDbContext();
    db.People.AddOrUpdate(person);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I would recommend not using AddOrUpdate during normal database usage. This method is intended only for seeding the database see [Julie Lerman's article](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/) for further explanation.

Comment: @Nick The article makes a good point.  However, if the devs are aware that the AddOrUpdate cannot be used to update just one property without first having the complete original object to preserve the other properties, then I wonder why not?  If you just have the primary key and want to ninja (only change) one or two properties, yes, coding it differently is required.  As for my answer for Elad, the method documentation does say "Equivalent to an 'upsert' operation from database terminology."

Comment: Apparently it's subject to race conditions because it's doing select first to find whether entity exists.

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov How would an upset be done (in EF) without a select first?

Comment: You can use unique key and simply insert. If you get an exception that means entity already exists. Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042107/handle-exceptions-in-entity-framework-4/34670770#34670770. This is an upsert: `DbUtils.IgnoreErrors(_db, () => DbUtils.InsertEntity(_db, someEntity),
  DbUtils.IsDuplicateInsertError);`

Comment: re:UniqueKey - yes, that will end up in error and duplicates will not be created, but still this is NOT an upsert. Doing this like aleksey wrote will result in a MISSING UPDATE. 
 We've just asked to IgnoreErrors, right? Right. So they will be ignored, and insert will fail and nothing more happens. Noone sends an UPDATE to finish the other part of this half-baked upsert. You have to check if the insert failed,and issue an update yourself. It's better to NOT ignore that error and to catch specific exception and retry. Or let the job be crashed and let some task manager retry whole transaction.

Answer (score 1):

"optimistic" approach for simple scenarios (demos)...
dbContext.Find()'s intellisense help tells us that it either retrieves entity by key if already present in current context, or queries the database to get it... then we know if it exists to either add or update. i'm using EFCore v2.2.0.

```
  var existing = _context.Find<InventoryItem>(new object[] {item.ProductId});
  if (existing == null) _context.Add(item);
  else existing.Quantity = item.Quantity;
  _context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: But this will fire select query based on the id and then either do insert or update.