# Why does my Content field return NULL since I initialized the variable and assigned to db field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem which I have no idea where I made mistake since I am beginner in ASP.NET CORE MVC.
I am creating a Ticketing System where the user can create a ticket and describe a problem. Once the ticket is sent
`Admin` can send a message to `User`. Right now, this is where the problem starts.
When I log in as `Admin` and try to answer the ticket, my message is always null or empty. I try to debug and see what happens and `Content` is always `null`.
Here is my GET method:

```cs
public IActionResult Upsert(int? Id)
{
    DiscussionTicketVM discTicketVM = new DiscussionTicketVM()
    {
        ApplicationUser = new ApplicationUser(),
        Discussion = new Discussion(),
        Ticket = new Ticket()
    };
    
    if (Id == null)
    {
        return View(discTicketVM);
    }
    
    discTicketVM.Discussion = _unitOfWork.Discussion.Get(Id.GetValueOrDefault());
    
    if (discTicketVM.Discussion == null)
    {
        NotFound();
    }
    
    return View(discTicketVM);
}
```

And here is my `POST` method where the magic starts

```cs
 public IActionResult Upsert(string message, int ticketId, DiscussionTicketVM discTikVM)
        {
            
            var users = _unitOfWork.ApplicationUser.GetAll(x => x.Id == x.UserName);
            var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            var user = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
           

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (discTikVM.Discussion.Id == 0)
                {
                   
                    _unitOfWork.Discussion.Add(discTikVM.Discussion);
                }
                else
                {
                    _unitOfWork.Discussion.Update(discTikVM.Discussion);
                }
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                return View(discTikVM);
            }

            return View(discTikVM);
        }
```

Regarding this I created DiscussionModel which is the following:

```cs
public class Discussion
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "Odgovor")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme")]
    public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    
    public int? TicketId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("TicketId")]
    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
}
```

And ViewModel:

```cs
public class DiscussionTicketVM
{
    public Discussion Discussion { get; set; }
    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

And also my View

```
    @model VmSTicketing.Models.ViewModels.DiscussionTicketVM
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "OpenDiscussion";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/AdminLTE/_Layout.cshtml";
        
    }
    
    <h2 class="text-info text-left">Odgovori na tiketu</h2>
    
    <!--StyleSheet-->
    <link href="~/css/discussion.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <div class="container padding-bottom-3x mb-2">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Discussion.Id" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="padding-top-2x mt-2 hidden-lg-up"></div>
                <!-- Messages-->
                <div class="comment">
                    <div class="comment-author-ava"><img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar6.png" alt="Avatar"></div>
                    <div class="comment-body">
                        <p class="comment-text"></p>
                        <div class="comment-footer" asp-for="Discussion.Content"><span class="comment-meta"></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <!-- Reply Form-->
                <h5 class="mb-30 padding-top-1x">Leave Message</h5>
                <form method="post" asp-controller="Discussion" asp-action="SendDisucssion">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea asp-for="Discussion.Content" class="form-control form-control-rounded"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" asp-controller="Discussion" asp-action="Upsert" type="submit">Submit Message</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-left">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Ticket">Nazad</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

A note before any discussion starts: I am trying to find a solution in google and I see that `SignalR` is one of the solutions to make real-time conversation, but in my case, I want first to create conversation and whatever before I update to SignalR, so I am not using `SignalR`.
Is there anyone who can guide me and tell me what to do in this case? Where did I make a mistake?
What should I focus on?

**UPDATE**

IUnitOfWorks.cs

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        T Get(int Id);

        IEnumerable<T> GetAll(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = null
            );

        IEnumerable<T> GetFirstOrDefault(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
            string includeProperties = null
            );

        void Add(T entity);
        void Remove(int Id);
        void Remove(T entity);
        void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entity);
    }

 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        internal DbSet<T> dbSet;

        public Repository(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
            this.dbSet = _db.Set<T>();
        }  


        public void Add(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public T Get(int Id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(Id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);

            }

            if(includeProperties != null)
            {
                foreach (var includeProp in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    query = query.Include(includeProp);
                }
            }

            if(orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }

            return query.ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetFirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, string includeProperties = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);

            }

            if (includeProperties != null)
            {
                foreach (var includeProp in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    query = query.Include(includeProp);
                }
            }

            yield return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public void Remove(int Id)
        {
            T entity = dbSet.Find(Id);
            Remove(entity);
        }

        public void Remove(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Remove(entity);
        }

        public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entity)
        {
            dbSet.RemoveRange(entity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: We can't know what `_unitOfWork`, `Get` etc are or what they do. They're definitely not EF classes, nor a common way of using EF. A DbContext is already a Unit-of-Work, a DbSet is already a repository. The `Upsert` method doesn't seem to be making any changes to the database.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Let me add these two class in my question

Comment: To "upsert" a detached entity you only need to re-attach it and set its state to `Added` or `Modified` as [the answer here shows]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195847/does-ef-upsert-have-to-be-done-manually). It's unclear what this `Upsert` is trying to do though - there's no entity and nothing is done if `Id` is null. *Maybe* you could load an existing instance with `DbSet.Find()` and modify it if `Id` isn't null, or create a new entity otherwise

Comment: The code you posted doesn't save changes anywhere, so whatever those classes do, no changes will be saved.

Comment: I update my code right now

Comment: This "repository" makes no changes to the database. A DbContext caches all changes in memory and only persists them when `SaveChanges` is called. Until then, it doesn't even  open a connection. That's why a DbContext already is a Unit-of-Work. If you want to discard the changes, just don't call `SaveChanges`. If you do want to persist the changes, a single `SaveChanges` call before returning from the action is enough. `SaveChanges` persists all changes (updates, deletes, inserts) using an internal transaction

Comment: Yes, I did this alredy. I call `SaveChanges` after all action is done, so after `else` block. 
Which you can check in my updated code